# How to get refresh token for the first time?

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-2.0, refresh-token, openiddict

When I request the `access token` for the very first time, am I not supposed to get `refresh token` as well?

I'm following .net core version of refresh flow logic ([Startup.cs,](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/RefreshFlow/AuthorizationServer/Startup.cs) [AuthorizationController.cs](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/RefreshFlow/AuthorizationServer/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs)) and testing with `postman` to get access token and refresh token. I can get access token, but seems like it is not returning refresh token.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I had to add an extra key&value in postman `Body`

Key: `scope`
Value: `openid offline_access`

[image]